# ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 4) are incompatible

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, cross-validation

I am trying to implement StratifiedKFold. I am using resnet50 for classification. I have 4 classes so I used softmax activation function in the last layer.
code snippets:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
# create the stratified k-fold cross-validator
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=42)

for train_index, val_index in skf.split(X_train, y_train):
    X_train_fold, X_val_fold = X_train[train_index], X_train[val_index]
    y_train_fold, y_val_fold = y_train[train_index], y_train[val_index]
    resnet152v2 = model.fit(X_train_fold, y_train_fold, batch_size=16, epochs=10, verbose=1)
    # val_loss, val_acc = model.evaluate(X_val_fold, y_val_fold, verbose=0)
    # print("Validation Loss: ", val_loss, "Validation Accuracy: ", val_acc)
```

Error: `ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 4) are incompatible`

**p.s:**

X_train_fold.shape = (492, 224, 224, 3)

y_train_fold.shape = (492,)

Comment: Please share the defined model code snippet to find the root cause of this error.